Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322) when trying to create a form using Prisma
so I'm trying to create a submitForm using prisma, react-hook-form and zod and mysql as my database. But the problem I'm encountering right now is I get this error on form-submit.ts
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

I know this comes from my schema.prisma, because upon reading the docs, on Scalar https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/reference/prisma-schema-reference#-modifier
model AppoinmentSchedule {
  id String @id @default(cuid())
  doesHaveTCETAssitance String
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt 
}

Since my zod accepts array.
export const formSchemaData = z.object({
    
    doesHaveTCETAssitance: z.array(z.string()).refine((value) => value.some((item) => item), {
      message: 'Please select at lease on the option'
    }),
   
  })

form-submit.ts

export const submitForm = async (
    values: z.infer<typeof formSchemaData>
) => {
    const validatedFields = formSchemaData.safeParse(values)

    if(!validatedFields.success){
        return {error: "Form not submitted successfully!"}
    }

    const {
        doesHaveTCETAssitance,
    } = validatedFields.data

    try {
        await db.appoinmentSchedule.create({
            data: {
                doesHaveTCETAssitance,
            }
        })
    } catch (error) {
        return {error: "Something went wrong"}
    }
}


This may be obvious to you already, but the error originates from your zod schema. I'm not fluent in it, but it seems like your validation returns a string array when doesHaveTCETAssitance (there's a typo, BTW) expects a string. Fix your zod schema to only return one string value.
